# Imprimir el resultado de los mensajes recibidos como suscriptor en un JTextArea

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para un proyecto de IoT usando el protocolo MQTT, mi problema radica en imprimir lo que recibo en estado de subscriber a un JTextArea. Intenté actualizar el JTextArea para cada ves que llegara un mensaje en messageArrived() y publicarlo en JTextArea pero no he podido, incluso intenté reemplazar y reasignar el contenido de la consola, pues en ésta imprime sin problema, pasándolo al JTextArea pero tampoco¡ Le he camellado mucho a esto y espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    try{
        /*
        String msj = new String(message.getPayload());
        System.out.println(msj);
        String topico = topic;        
        subscribingArea.setText(msj);
        //subscribingArea.repaint();
        */
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream( new CustomOutputStream( subscribingArea ) );

        System.setOut( out );
        System.setErr( out );
        System.out.println(new String(message.getPayload()));

    }catch(Exception e){
        setTitleText( "No se pudo imprimir la cadena" );
    }

}
```

Es la función en donde llegan los mensajes del protocolo MQTT. A parte he implementado la clase para que me reemplace los contenidos, hablando del método PrintStream.

```
package com.mycompany.clientefinalpc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public CustomOutputStream( JTextArea textArea ) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));

    }}
```

Y la parte del código donde construyo los elementos.

```
public void connectButton( Container contentPane ){
        setTitleText( "" );        

        //pubPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout() );
        subPanel.setBorder( new EtchedBorder() );
        pubPanel.setBorder( new EtchedBorder() ); 

        mqttComp = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        mqttComp.add( subPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        mqttComp.add( pubPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        mqttComp.add( subscribePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        ledNoLocalClient = new LED();
        ledNoLocalClient.setRed();
        new Thread(ledNoLocalClient).start();

        ledLocalClient = new LED();
        ledLocalClient.setRed();
        new Thread(ledLocalClient).start();

        //pubPanelControl = new PubPanel(publishPanel, aMqttMgr);
        //subPanelControl = new SubPanel(subscribePanel, aMqttMgr);

        disconnect = new JButton( "Desconectar" );        
        disconnect.addActionListener(this);

        publishButton = new JButton( "Publica" );
        publishButton.addActionListener(this);

        subscribingArea = new JTextArea(15,30);
        subscribingArea.setEditable( false );
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(subscribingArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 350,290 ) );  

        publish = new JTextField();
        publish.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 150,30 ) );
        publish.setEditable( true );
        publish.setText( "PUBLICA ALGO" );

        JPanel _button = new JPanel();
        _button.add( new JLabel( "Local Status" ) );
        _button.add( disconnect );  

        JPanel _text = new JPanel();
        _text.add( publish );
        _text.add( publishButton );
        _text.add( new JLabel( "Remote Status" ) );
        _text.add( ledNoLocalClient );

        JPanel _area = new JPanel();
        _area.add( scrollpane );

        pubPanel.add(ledLocalClient); 
        subscribePanel.add( _area );
        pubPanel.add(_button);   
        subPanel.add(_text);  

        contentPane.add( mqttComp );
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Cristhian. ¿Qué significa `subscribingArea`, de qué tipo es esa variable, existe información para entender como se obtiene información de allí?

Comment: El subscribingArea, es el JTextArea en donde quiero imprimir, en el método public void connectButton(), lo estoy construyendo.

Comment: Ok, entendido. No he trabajado antes con MQTT, por lo cual yo empezaría por crear un programa sencillo que me permita interactuar con el dispositivo mediante dicho protocolo e imprimir la salida de la interacción en consola. Una vez que tenga eso, dependiendo de los mecanismos de captura de los resultados de comunicación, puesto que termino obteniendo información en forma de texto, en lugar de escribirlo en el stream de salida habitual `System.out` lo escribiría en otro componente como el `JTextArea` u otro. No sé si me dejo entender.

Comment: Si, de hecho si ves la partee del @override messageArrived, tengo implementado dos códigos porque como mencioné, he intentado con muchas cosas... el problema es que éste, no imprime así¡ porque?? no tengo ni idea..¡ entonces la verdad no he podido hallar con el problema¡

Comment: Para temas de actualización de GUI's en "real time" es bueno saber que este tipo de cosas deben hacerse mediante otro Thread. ¿Has intentado algo así?

Comment: Bueno, si lo he intentado sin embargo de seguro no lo he hecho correctamente porque no he obtenido la solución deseada pero, si¡ si lo he intentado¡ tienes alguna propuesta o algo así?

Comment: Vale, según leo; el mensaje llega y lo puedes imprimir por consola ¿cierto? si es así, entonces lo que te digo es lo que te puede estar pasando. Lo importante es estar seguros de que el mensaje llega correctamente, presentarlo en pantalla debe ser lo de menos ;) Me confirmas.

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza un poco, es que estuve un poco ocupado, y si¡ el mensaje llega a la consola, pero cuando intento setear el JTextArea desde otra función como el messageArrived(), no setea nada, pero si¡ el mensaje claramente lleva bien a la consola

Comment: Hola Cristhian actualmente estoy empezando a utilizar MQTT me podras dar informacion sobre ese proyecto que hiciste? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido dar con una respuesta, casualmente para los observadores, estaba ejecutando un segundo frame y éste debía realizar unos procesos los cuales no estaba ejecutando, para ello he eliminado el segundo frame y lo he implementado todo en el primero y ha funcionado correctamente, para actualizar el frame he usado solamente, append(), que me escribe una nueva línea cada que llega un nuevo mensaje.